# How to defer multiple CSS files with Google Page Speed CSS load script

Tags: javascript

I use Google Page Speed CSS load script to defer the my larger css file.

```
<script async>
    var cb = function() {
        var l = document.createElement('link');
        l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.href = '<?php echo $root; ?>css/custom.css';
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
    };
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(cb);
    else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

How can I also defer these scripts?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: What's the point? Any trick that loads CSS after page render will cause a flash of unstyled content.

Comment: @SalmanA Hi, you can read about it here https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: Based on the example, you can modify the cb function to load as many stylesheets as you want using a loop. But FOUC issue will remain there.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes sir the questions is about how the code will look. Do you mind answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the code sample:

```
var loadCSSFiles = function() {
    var links = ["//example.com/css/custom.css", "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans", "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"],
        headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        linkElement, i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkElement = document.createElement("link");
        linkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
        linkElement.href = links[i];
        headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    }
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) {
    raf(loadCSSFiles);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load", loadCSSFiles);
}
```

Note: I changed `insertBefore` to `appendChild`, the former seems incorrect as it would place the stylesheets outside the document head.

Comment: Does this thing actually works? because I've done the same an in "PageSpeed Suggestions " section I have the same number of suggestion - more, when i open "PageSpeed Insights" I have even more problems then before doing that.

Only way that actually worked for me was to append a single style with this method above the other that I declare speciffic in head section